# PHP - rowCount() giving the same value regardless if the string exists or not

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following code:

```
$queryMobileNumber = $dbh->prepare("SELECT mobile_number FROM $tableBusinessOwner WHERE business_owner_id = $businessOwnerIDTable");
$queryMobileNumber->bindValue( 1, $mobileNumberNew);
$queryMobileNumber->execute();

echo $businessOwnerIDTable;
echo '-';
echo $queryMobileNumber->rowCount();
```

I connect to my database using PDO.

The above checks whether a mobile number inserted by the user already exists in the table or not. Regardless if the number exists or not when I echo `$queryMobileNumber->rowCount();` the value is always 1.

I am not sure what I'm missing. I am not getting any error in my error_log.

Comment: This looks like poor design. Why is the table name variable?

Answer (score 2):

As explained by the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

> PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.
>
> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.

Since you're doing a select, `rowCount()` is not the function you're looking for.

What can you do instead?

```
<?php

$queryMobileNumber = $dbh->prepare("SELECT mobile_number FROM $tableBusinessOwner WHERE business_owner_id = $businessOwnerIDTable");
$queryMobileNumber->execute();

$res = $queryMobileNumber->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $businessOwnerIDTable;
echo '-';
if(!empty($res['mobile_number')){
  echo $res['mobile_number'); //or whatever else
} else {
  echo 'N/A';
}
```

Comment: Hi, it is after another `SELECT` statement... how can I go about it? I want to count the number of rows that contain a particular record. I want to COUNT not output the value of `mobile_number`

Comment: what about... COUNT(*)? `SELECT count(mobile_number) FROM $tableBusinessOwner WHERE business_owner_id = $businessOwnerIDTable`

Answer (score 0):

You have always to fetch any query you execute in order to get the query's data.. Try this

```
$queryMobileNumber->execute();

$result = $queryMobileNumber->fetchAll();
echo $result->rowCount();
```

[see documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetch.php)

The rowCount of the query you execute (select, insert, delete) will return how many times your query was executed

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in this example: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php#example-1009

> For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will be returned. Your application can then perform the correct action.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fruit WHERE calories > 100";
if ($res = $conn->query($sql)) {
/* Check the number of rows that match the SELECT statement */
  if ($res->fetchColumn() > 0) {
   ...
```

If you just want to check if a number exists, the procedure count is less demanding for mysql